# Why doesn't git repo checkout the branch specified?

Tags: git, repo, git-repo

I've just started a new job where they're using [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/). There's an XML manifest file that contains all the different repos that looks like:

```
    <project path="company/project-name"
    name="project-name.git"
    remote="company-server"
    revision="current-branch" />
```

But this doesn't setup that branch for that repo. If I open the directory and type `git status` I get:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at 1234567
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This means I can't do a `git pull`:

```
$ git pull
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

I have to do a `git checkout` of the correct branch to fix it:

```
$ git checkout current-branch
Branch 'current-branch' set up to track remote branch 'current-branch' from 'company-server'.
Switched to a new branch 'current-branch'
```

Then I can do `git pull` successfully.

Is this how git-repo is intended to work? It seems wrong to me. Or is there any way to get it to checkout the branches properly?

Comment: Did you ask your colleagues?

Comment: I know nothing about git-repo, but a detached head is no big deal, it just means that some particular commit was checked out and is not named by any branch. And checking out a commit by its branch name is indeed what you do if you want to proceed to do anything. So, while I don't know why the repo came to you in a detached head state, I wouldn't worry about it if I were you.